# Create Pointer or Arrow at the top right side of a div

Tags: jquery, css

How can I do this with CSS and/or JQuery including JQueryUI

but not mooTools....

I have been trying to do this with CSS :before :after arrow.top etc. etc.
I can get an arrow, sometimes with a rectangle rotated and sometimes with
a :before but toggling the parameters to try to get the right placement does
not seem to get it in the right place.

I just have a button at the top of strip of my page, and I want to click it
and load the div with `$("ul li div)` elements.

[image]

I think the lack of specific term for this type of UI element is the reason
it has been difficult to describe what I want to. 'Arrow' or 'Pointer' is too
generic.  I also tried using the Jquery UI tooltip but I could not get it load
a list of ul->li items fetched from an AJAX call.  Also was playing with the
JQuery UI dialog.  Perhaps because I am trying to do this in many different 
ways.  I guess I should just start with some divs and work from there.

Anyhow an image is worth a 1000 words, so here is an example.....I will delete
my other question.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to explain a bit further what you're trying to achieve here. You have a button in a div at the top of your page that you want to change the cursor for? You haven't explained this well.

Comment: Please provide code and *please* make some sort of effort...

Comment: I see you've already tried to ask this same question. That was worded a little more clearly and your problem description makes much more sense. Perhaps this question could be closed and people work to help you with that one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791580/load-a-ul-element-with-li-from-a-getjson-call-in-jquery-ui-tooltip

Comment: I know it has been driving me crazy.  I am in the middle of a sprint and trying to figure this out.  Maybe I have to just take a picture of it.  It is common on gmail, facebook, and linkedin.  A button, it notifies you of new messages, you click on it and a dropdown but full of UL->LI-> divs ....It has an arrow at the top which points to the button you just pressed.

Comment: @magister this should help http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: thanks alot Pete...this is what I was after, I will accept this as an answer, although I have lost point because of this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear but I think you want something like [**this :**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/pzpDj/)

**HTML :**

```
<div class="containner">
    Hello
    <div class="arrow arrow-right"></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.containner {
    width:100px;
    height;100px;
    border:solid black 1px;
    text-align:center;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#ccc;
    color:#fff;
}
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 10px solid #fff;
    float:right;
}

.arrow-down {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #fff;
    float:right;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
    font-size:1px;
}
```

**JS :**

```
$('.containner').on('click', function(){
    // other code
    $(this).find('.arrow').toggleClass('arrow-right arrow-down')
});
```